# PatternSyntaxException: while using String.ReplaceAll function in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, junit

I got a patternsyntax exception when i am trying to do a String.ReplaceAll.

**Below is my String**

```
Number of testcases to execute : 39?    Starting execution of test case : testCreateDAta?    The class that has completed its execution is : test.com.mySpace.service.ejb.session.MyTest?     Finished execution of test case : testCreateDAta?    Starting execution of test case : testUpdate?
```

What i was trying to do:

```
junitReportString.replaceAll("?", "\n");
```

The above code fetched me the below exception:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 0
```

Then i tried again with the below code:

```
junitReportString.replaceAll("\\?", "\n");
```

The above code fetched me the same String that i mentioned above.

My Complete Code:

```
String junitReportString=new String();
myApp= new URL("http://localhost:port/testWeb/TestJunit.jsp");
URLConnection yc = myApp.openConnection();
yc.connect();
junitReportString=yc.getHeaderField("finalJUNITReport").toString();
System.out.println(junitReportString);
junitReportString.replaceAll("\\?", "\n");
System.out.println("Report Details     ==============>"+junitReportString);
```

What is wrong with my code. Any guidance much appreciated.

Comment: Your code `replaceAll("\\?", "\n");` works for me..

Comment: I am not able to print the String in the new line. :(

Comment: could you post your full code?

Comment: I think I know what's going on. You need to assign the string back to the variable: `junitReportString = junitReportString.replaceAll("\\?", "\n");`

Comment: @AvinashRaj : i have posted my whole code.

Comment: @Davio : tHANKS TO YOU TOO.. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) does not change the actual `String` it just returns new `String` which contains the changes.

```
junitReportString=junitReportString.replaceAll("\\?", "\n"); 
//Now you have changed String
```

Comment: OMG..So silly of me...Thanks Buddy..On the target you were.. B-)